# Unknown huge Volatge drop over a resistor

Tags: resistors, voltage-regulator, diodes

I am still learing about the basic electrical engineering and here I have a project for my univ and have some problems.

So my problem is rather weird in my opinion maybe because the lack of knowledge. As you can see in my schematic below I have a 16v power source with 68 mA current (measured with multimeter) but then after the resistor it dropped down to 4 voltage so the LP 2950 cant regulate the voltage properly.
Then I remove the resistor just for trial and error purposes and it worked perfectly fine.
Since I was suggested to use the resistor before by my profesor therefore i can't remove it, the reason was the diode will be broken if it is used for a long time. 
And here are my questions:

- is it true what my professor said? if yes(or no) what is the reason
  for it?
- What is the possible reason of the resistor's huge voltage drop?
- What is the solution to this problem?
- will it be any different if it was a schottky diode?

### IMPORTANT NOTE

1. All the components work perfectly (checked everything twice).
2. All the connection to soldering also works fine.
3. without the resistor the current i=200 mA
4. The diode is necessary to avoid mixing signal
5. The 4700uF capacitor is also necessary

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2femwUc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

THank you for your time.

Comment: Please elaborate "4. The diode is necessary to avoid mixing signal".

Comment: Well, apply the standard laws for the voltage dropped over 150Ω at 68mA and see how much it drops, then add the diode drop

Comment: You are overloading the circuit. The regulator is rated for 100mA and the resistor is designed for 68mA but you are taking much too much on the output side. Maybe your can reduce the resistor to 100-120Ohm and get 100mA from the circuit but you should check your load. I suspect your load is well above 200mA@3.3V.

Comment: A 7805 is going to dropout at around 7V input

Comment: @sstobbe it's not a 7805 though,,, he just drew it that way and changed the U# not the Part#

Comment: @Trevor good catch, yes if that's a to-92 regulator you'll need to burn the power somewhere else like the series resistor, I would add preregulator that can handle the power dissipation of being on 16 V supply, a scale R1 back.

Comment: Rja temp rise in tiny TO-92 is 100'C/W , while TO-220 is much lower where [watt]Pd=I*ΔV (drop)  Choose series R  to match Rja thermal resistance to define voltage drop and thus Pd and thus junction T rise according to ratings. (size) In future make Vin closer to Vout for "linear LDO." recognizing Vdrop min. , But 16 to 5V is a huge drop  also http://aosmd.com/res/application_notes/package/AN101_TO220_Guidelines.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> •is it true what my professor said? if yes(or no) what is the reason for it?

Yes. You are charging a rather large capacitor. Without the resistor, when power is first applied there will be a large voltage drop across the diode and the initial in-rush current will also be large. This will cause significant strain on the diode.

> •What is the possible reason of the resistor's huge voltage drop?

V=IR. Though your 68mA at 150R should actually be 10.2V dropped across the resistor, so at least one of your numbers is not correct.

> •What is the solution to this problem?

What problem? If the drop is too much reduce the resistor size.

> •will it be any different if it was a schottky diode?

Yes, a shottky / germanium diode will buy you about 0.4 to 0.5V more voltage at the input to the regulator

Comment: And to do the maths for you... To aim for 9 V at the regulator, drop around 6 V on the resistor. 6/0.068 = 88 so aim for an 82 or 91 ohm resistor. That will give an inrush at the diode of under 200 mA which should be fine.  You should then be good up to around 90 mA load current (If we want 7V at the regulator max drop = 8.4 V, 8.4/88 = 95 mA), anything more than that and you'll start having problems again.

Answer (score 3):

One of the most basic electrical engineering formulas is Ohm's Law $$E = iR $$

With current (i) in amps and (R) in ohms, for your circuit the voltage drop across the resistor is $$E = iR = .068 \times 150 = 10.2 \text{ volts} $$ And, of course, I'll just bet that your resistor is not a 1% unit, but perhaps a 10% tolerance. Then the actual resistance could be 165 ohms, for a drop of 11.2 volts. Add 0.7 volts for the diode, and 4 volts sounds just about right.

Furthermore, you need to read the specs on your multimeter. It will measure current by putting a resistor in series and measuring the voltage across the resistor. There is no reason to assume that the shunt resistor your meter uses is negligeable. Let's assume that it is 10 ohms. Then the effective total resistance is 175 ohms for a voltage drop of 11.9 volts with the meter in place, for an output voltage of 4.1 volts, and less if you count the diode.

So you need to find the manual for your meter (or look it up on the web) and determine just what your current measurement burden (that's the technical term) is. You also need to use the meter to measure your 150 ohm resistor. Additionally, you need to measure your 16 volt supply to make sure it is not actually putting out something like, say, 15 volts. And finally, you need to measure the current without the resistor in place. This would not be important if it were not for your statement "it dropped down to 4 voltage so the LP 2950 cant regulate the voltage properly." According to the spec sheet, at the maximum rated 100 mA load, the dropout voltage should be less than 0.5 volts, so a 3.3 volt unit should be quite happy with a 4 volt input. So, as user3528438  commented, it seems very likely that you are drawing too much current for the regulator. If so, the obvious next step is to provide a separate regulator for each unit.

Comment: well explained and easily understood thank you for your tips and explaination